# horizontal ScrollView Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I have a horizontal ScrollView implemented and working. however, when I Scrol horizontally he walks, but when he returns to deslargo initial position no reason for it.

Anyone know a solution?

Thanks

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  Height="50" Width="Auto">
   <StackPanel Name="sp_urlsHome" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50" Width="Auto">
        <TextBlock Text="adasdasdsasdfffffffffffffffffffffffffsdfsdfsdfsdfsfsdfdas"/>
   </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set right `ScrollViewer` `Width`. Inner control will scroll only if it `Width` is greater that `ScrollViewer` `Width`. Check that moment, please (`ScrollViewer`  should not resize while increasing content size)

Just posted your code into blank page and it works fine